# How to get pending transactions from Yodlee API?

Tags: yodlee

Would like to get not only posted transactions but also the pending ones from the Yodlee REST API.

It seems possible according to [Yodlee's documentation](http://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions#How_do_I_retrieve_only_posted_transactions.3F)

Here's the code:

```
transactions_url = "https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/TransactionSearchService/executeUserSearchRequest"
transactions_data = {
    "cobSessionToken": self.cob_session_token,
    "userSessionToken": self.user_session_token,
    "transactionSearchRequest.containerType": "All",
    "transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit": 1000,
    "transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit": 1,
    "transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber": 20,
    "transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber": 1,
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId": 1,
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName": "DataSearchService",
    "transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput": True,
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode": "USD",
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate": "12-01-2013",
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate": "12-16-2013",
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionStatus": 2,
    "transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType": "ALL_TRANSACTION",
}

res = requests.post(transactions_url, transactions_data)
```

Sending in the key-val pair `"transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionStatus", 2` gives me the following error:

```
{
    "errorOccured": "true",
    "exceptionType": "Exception Occured",
    "refrenceCode": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The API returns all the transactions present for the account which includes both pending and posted transactions. You need to check the status of the transaction in the response returned to you which will be marked as pending or posted.
Hence you need not pass this explicitly but if you want to get only pending transactions try passing the parameter as below

"transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionStatus.statusId" with id as 2.

Please make sure the account has a pending transaction to get this an appropriate response.

Comment: I have never been able to see pending transactions.  When I search without any transaction status in the search filter I get posted transactions.  If I add the "transactionStatus.statusId" and explicitly set it to 1, I get posted transactions back.  If I explicitly set it to 2, I get nothing and the executeUserSearchRequest returns a null instead of a valid search ID.

Comment: Hey David,If the account has pending transactions in our DB , you will for sure get the pending transactions for that account. Try using the dag account and editing the xml to have pending transctions in it and then add that dag account and then try pulling transaction for the itemAccountId which gets created. You should be able to get pending transactions. To know more about dag check this -https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Indy_FinApp_Knowledgebase/Sample_Data/Dummy_Account_Generator

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me once I added another bank that has pending transactions in the database.  Is there any documentation on which banks include pending transactions and which do not?

Comment: No David, There is no such documentation due to the long list of FIs which Yodlee supports.

Answer (score 1):

FYI : I'm currently running tests to get today's transactions (we have major issues with this) and although i still have not successfully done this I can successfully get back transaction ***without supplying From and To dates*** as paramteters. Not sure if this helps any one else.

My test also show which formats can get a positive result

"MM-dd-yyyy" **PASS** - get a correctly formatted search result with transactions

"yyyy-dd-MMTHH:mm:ss.000Z" **FAIL** - format supplied by yodlee support. *
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z" **FAIL** - ISO equivalent of format supplied by yodlee support **
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" **FAIL** - ISO standard format using Z to imply UTC - no milliseconds **
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00" **FAIL** - ISO standard format - No Z - no Milliseconds **

* returns
`{ "searchIdentifier":{},"numberOfHits":0 }`

** returns

```
{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException","referenceCode":"_d87c92ac-0eed-449e-
a14d-7ac78443c2fe","message":"Invalid argument value: Start date cannot be great than end date"}
```

Comment: By doing a refresh (jsonsdk/Refresh/startSiteRefresh) and polling for the refresh status (jsonsdk/Refresh/getSiteRefreshInfo) and not using the date parameters I was able to get todays transactions using the execute search. This is even though a fast link created consumer should get the days transactions. BTW this is not inline with the docs that say dates are required fields (obviously they are not), so they could change the service behavior to make it a breaking change.

Comment: were you able to get today's transactions or the transactions that posted today? It seems they are all posted together in batches, so I get days that have 0 and days that have hundreds. Wish transactionDate was a default param.

Comment: we were able get the transactions but with much to-ing- and fro-ing with yodlee support. Changes have been made to their back end and i believe they have finally acknowledged their timezone handling is incorrect. I would recommend hitting up your support person as the API  (or at least the internal implementation) has most likely change since this was posted